# Hi i am working on this project regarding localization of a mobile robot using laser scanner and odometry ( encoder sensors) using labview

Tags: slam

I have a Sick laser scanner LMS 100 attached with my robot which scans the environment. Data acquistion is already done for the laser scanner and now  Encoder sensor attached on the wheel gives the distance travelled by the robot. A map in indoor room is already given in our case which consists of 3 landmarks.I am working in Labview environment.My question is now how can i localize the robot based on distance and angle?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have 2 point clouds, one complete map and one partial scan of the environment. The [Iterative Closes point method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point) (used in SLAM Methods) can give you the your postion on the map based on the partial scan.

Answer (score 0):

You can localize the robot using dead reckoning with the encoders alone, but the result would be very inaccurate. What is the representation of the landmarks? Also, what do you mean by localize using distance and angle? Are you saying you have the distance and angle to each landmark? Please provide more information.